# psql:routing_dd.sql:28 ERROR

Tags: pgrouting

psql:routing_dd.sql:28: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/librouting_dd.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/librouting_dd.so: undefined symbol: __gmpq_equal

Have no compile errors afaik or have seen.

As soon as I'd like to import my DD extra functions it's not working properly: (dash) With Driving Distance
psql -U postgres -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_dd.sql routing
psql -U postgres -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_dd_wrappers.sql routing

Versions:
PostgreSQL 9.1
pgRouting - git'ed this morning (1.05?)
CGAL 3.9

Any idea? Read that some similar isues have been fixed not long ago...

Thanks!

---

Is not working!

V1:

- Postgresql 9.1
- Postgis
- pgRouting freshly gitted
- all compiled from scratch
  --> FAIL

V2:

- Postgresql 9.1
- Postgis
- pgRouting
- all deps and libs downloaded from ubuntu repository
  --> Still not working!

Hopefully this will be fixed: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/48#issuecomment-2789012

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure pgRouting is supposed to work with PG 9.1?

Comment: Good call, underdark, I seem to recall from the pgRouting session at FOSS4G that it didn't work with 9.1 yet.

Comment: looks like. :( - same setup without the DD is working though. Which is the fastest and most reliable version for pgrouting and mapnik atm?

Comment: https://transfer.data-logistic.com/files/get.php?t=5xfcu2jjgvlg0e2uledc54l9mbbdceqpbk32wkmc
You can download my log files from this morning here.

I already opend an issue on pgRouting@git - hope to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fix of this bug available now and it will be applied to master branch soon. 
See the related comment for more information: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/48#issuecomment-3005289

I can confirm that the fix solves the issue on Ubuntu 11.10 with PostgreSQL 9.1 and CGAL 3.8.